# Determining number of integer solutions of Diophantine equation

Tags: divisibility, diophantine-equations, gcd-and-lcm

Question:

How many integer solutions (consisting of two integers x and y) does the equation below have? Note: You are not required to find any solutions if there are any.

$ 294x + 266y = 28$

My attempt:

I am not sure what the question means by "how many". We know that gcd$(294,266)$ divides $28$ so there are infinitely many solutions to this Diophantine equation.

Comment: Well, that's your answer then.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ther are infinite solutions.

Given $294x + 266y = 28$, we can see that $\gcd(294, 266) = 14$ divides the answer, $28$, so solutions are feasible.

Dividing the equation through by $14$, we get $21x+19y=2$. Clearly $(x,y) = (1,-1)$ is a solution and for any solution $(x,y)=(k,\ell)$ we will have $(k+19, \ell-21)$ and  $(k-19, \ell+21)$ will also be solutions. Hence there are an infinite number of solutions.

In general after the division we will have coprime coefficients so using [Bézout's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) we can adjust the values of $x$ and $y$ to give any integer answer and then generate the infinite set similarly to above.

Answer (score 0):

By a convoluted process we can find
$$294x + 266y = 28\quad\implies x = -19 n - 18 \quad\land\quad y = 21 n + 20 \quad\land\quad n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
This can be verified in a spreadsheet showing the samples below

\begin{align*}
&(\space n\quad x\quad y\quad294x + 266y - 28)\\
&(-4,58,-64,0)\\
&(-3,39,-43,0)\\
&(-2,20,-22,0)\\
&(-1,1,-1,0)\\
&(0,-18,20,0)\\
&(1,-37,41,0)\\
&(2,-56,62,0)\\
&(3,-75,83,0)\\
&(4,-94,104,0)\\
\end{align*}
Note that the last element is alway zero meaning all $(x,y)$ shown are valid. Since these are all derived from the set of integers $(\mathbb{Z})$, there are infinite solutions to the equation.

Answer (score 0):

$294x+266y=28$

Dividing by $14$ we get an equation with the same solutions

$21x+19y=2$

The equality $A=B$ implies that $A\equiv B\pmod m$ for any $m \in Z$

$21x+19y\equiv 2 (mod 19)$

$2x\equiv 2 (mod 19)$

$gcd(2;19)=1$

So we can divide by 2

$x\equiv 1 (mod 19)$

$x=19k+1$

We can substitute this into our equation

$21(19k+1)+19y=2$

$21\times19k+21+19y=2$

$19y=2-21\times19k-21$

$19y=-21\times19k-19$

$y=-21k-1$

$(19k+1; -21k-1)$ solves the equation for every $k\in Z$, therefore the equation has infinitly many solutions